# How to validate text-boxes in onblur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textboxes in my page, I want to validate the TextBoxes in onblur event.  But onblur event is continuously executing for those 2 textboxes,

Please check the below code-

```js
function validate(c) {
  if (c.value == '') {
    alert(c.id + " is empty.");
    c.select();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="Text1" onblur="return validate(this)" />
      <input type="text" id="Text2" onblur="return validate(this)" />

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Please let me know, How to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean the blur event is continuously running for each text input?

Comment: If you deselect the first input by selecting the second input, and if the first input is invalid according to your function, then you essentially enter an "endless blur loop" because input1 is focused again when its invalid which causes the blur event on input2 which then gains focus and input1 is again blurred. this repeats forever.

Comment: @Mic1780 that sounds logical, but I cannot repeat that behaviour, neither on Firefox 42.0 nor Chrome 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit). Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It's working for me as well in Edge.. and no I can't follow the logic of @Mic1780 - this would only happen if both are blurred at the same time, wich can't happen?

Comment: ok it does happen when you are in 1 and click in 2, but in the example "alert()" is actually fixing the problem :D

Comment: Looks like i am wrong. Sorry for bad info. Here was my testing: https://jsfiddle.net/zrkz752p/

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

With `document.activeElement` you can check what the new focused Element is.

So you can for example do this:

```
function validate(c) {
    // Ignore when switching between these Inputs
    if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById("Text1")) return
    if (document.activeElement == document.getElementById("Text2")) return
    //...
```

*... took me some time to find the solution, by here it is*